# How to convert text JSON: a way to standardize outputs with Hugging Face and Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition, huggingface-tokenizers

Total newbie to Hugging Face and AI here.

My goal is to convert an input text to a standardized structure that would allow me, later on, to process tabulated data in JSON format.

For example,

Input: “Give me a list of all clients having purchased milk”

Output: `{"intention": "retrieve", "object": "client", "conditions":['purchase', 'milk']}`

Input: “Please, machine, do me a favor and delete users not having logged in after 2022”

Output `{"intention": "delete", "object": "user", "conditions":['logged-in', '2022-12-31']}`

The output JSON structure has fixed keys (`intention`, `object`, `conditions`) and values can be either discrete (for example `intention` can only be `['retrieve', 'delete', 'modify']`) or variable (for example `conditions` can contain any piece of data.

My approach would be to use named entity recognition (NER) to identify the relevant entities and their properties, and syntactic parsing to determine the structure of the user’s prompt. For example, the “Give me a list” would result in the entity `intention` to be `retrieve`.

After reading, watching, and practicing, I think I’m now totally lost and not even sure the NER approach is advisable in this context.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: Nope. The NER approach seems ruled out. Using system inputs in GPT4 to force a JSON response works-ish, but seems weak. Training a model seems the only option for now, but feels too specific to a particular JSON structure.